# How to get inner div at the top of outer div

Tags: html, css

I have this situation:

[image]

I want the table on the right side to be at the same height as the form on the left side.

Here is my CSS:

```
.left {
height: auto;
width: 550px;
}

.right {
height: auto;
width: 550px;
padding-left: 40px;
}

.innerRight {
height: auto;
}

.middle {
height: auto;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:17%;
bottom:15%;
border-left:1px solid grey;
}

.left, .right {
display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I do this?

I used floating, but then the height doesn't adjust automatically, so I can't used it.

Comment: would be nice if you give us HTML + CSS Maybe in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could give them both `position:absolute;` then position them with top, left, right, ect..

Comment: I tried that, but then the height of the outer div doesn't adjust automatically to the height of table on the right

Comment: @Bouss Remove the height:auto; from all the classes, what effect does it give?

Answer (score 0):

Without your actual HTML code, here is an example that might help you by using the `table-row`, `table-cell` css property.

```css
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.left {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.middle {
  border-left: solid 1px red;
  width: 1px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">Lorem</div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```